# Bug in Security Impersonation

Tags: symfony, impersonation

I probably found a bug in the identity impersonalization part of the security package.

You are trying to connect with $nonExistentUsername randomly generated, but if the username is a UUID and the database is PostgreSql, this causes an error : SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation
because the string you randomly generate is not a valid UUID and cannot be converted to UUID...

For trying, i disable the line 160 of SwitchUserListener.php and all works fine...

But, need a more robust solution :)

Allan

Comment: If you think that there is any bug, please report it to Symfony's issue tracker. If you are only looking for a fix, share more details - why should one use a username that "is a UUID", and why should that be treated in any other way than a usual string-based username?

Comment: Could you please add the code you changed, as the line 160 may differ in each symfony version.

Comment: i just change the £nonExistentUsername creation (.$nonExistentUsername = uuid_create(UUID_TYPE_RANDOM); ) line 152 in version 5.0.5